# Character vector to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data in the format below. The first element of vector refers to header and through second to bottom of vector refers to values against the header. I want to put data in the tabular / structured format (or data frame with header and values).

```
k <- c("Afv.dato : Type Termin lalt Betalt pa termin Terminsbelgb", "13-09-2019 opkrzvning 11-09-2019 4.067,11",
  "18-10-2019 indbetaling 4.067,00 11-09-2019 4.067,00", "11-12-2019 opkrzvning 11-12-2019 9.176,00" ,
  "18-12-2019 indbetaling 9.176,11 11-09-2019 0,11", "11-12-2019 9.176,00", "11-03-2020 opkreevning 11-03-2020 9.176,00", 
  "02-03-2020 indbetaling 9.176,00 11-03-2020 9.176,00", "11-06-2020 opkraevning 11-06-2020 9.176,00",
  "18-05-2020 indbetaling 9,176,00 11-06-2020 9.176,00"         
)
```

**Desired Output (values of first 5 rows (incld. header)**
[image]

Comment: How do you wish to interpret the row `"11-12-2019 9.176,00"`?

Comment: I wonder how to process the data with unequal columns and no indicator of missing value...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it with `strcapture`.

```
strcapture("(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+) *(\\D*) *(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)* *([0-9.,]*) *(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)* *([0-9.,]*)",
 k[-1], data.frame(Afv.dato=character(), Type=character(), Termin=character(),
 lalt=character(), "Betalt pa termin"=character(), Terminsbelgb=character()))
#    Afv.dato         Type     Termin     lalt Betalt.pa.termin Terminsbelgb
#1 13-09-2019  opkrzvning  11-09-2019 4.067,11                              
#2 18-10-2019 indbetaling             4.067,00       11-09-2019     4.067,00
#3 11-12-2019  opkrzvning  11-12-2019 9.176,00                              
#4 18-12-2019 indbetaling             9.176,11       11-09-2019         0,11
#5 11-12-2019                         9.176,00                              
#6 11-03-2020 opkreevning  11-03-2020 9.176,00                              
#7 02-03-2020 indbetaling             9.176,00       11-03-2020     9.176,00
#8 11-06-2020 opkraevning  11-06-2020 9.176,00                              
#9 18-05-2020 indbetaling             9,176,00       11-06-2020     9.176,00
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do something like this. The idea, is that read_lines() will put each element of your vector in a row. After that, you give this result to a function that you would tipically use for reading flat files. These functions generally uses the first row of the file as the column name.

```
library(readr) 

k <- c("Afv.dato : Type Termin lalt Betalt pa termin Terminsbelgb", "13-09-2019 opkrzvning 11-09-2019 4.067,11",
       "18-10-2019 indbetaling 4.067,00 11-09-2019 4.067,00", "11-12-2019 opkrzvning 11-12-2019 9.176,00" ,
       "18-12-2019 indbetaling 9.176,11 11-09-2019 0,11", "11-12-2019 9.176,00", "11-03-2020 opkreevning 11-03-2020 9.176,00", 
       "02-03-2020 indbetaling 9.176,00 11-03-2020 9.176,00", "11-06-2020 opkraevning 11-06-2020 9.176,00",
       "18-05-2020 indbetaling 9,176,00 11-06-2020 9.176,00"         
)

read_csv(read_lines(k))
```

Comment: This would work if OP's data were delimited, but the issue they are asking for help with is needing to figure out which column the data goes in based on order and data type. See, for example, in the expected output that the 2nd row of the `Termin` column is blank, but this is not indicated in the sample input.

Comment: Also, I don't think `read_lines` accomplishes anything here. `read_lines(k)` is the same as `k`.